# Ionic 2/angular 2 - How do I add HTML elements with Typescript to my component?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, typescript2.0

**Please don't dislike judging by the title, read the post first.**

I've just started out learning typescript and angular 2 working with the ionic 2 framework.

I'm adding the html element referencing the typscript variable "newItem", like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of todos" (click)="edit(item)">
      {{item}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>test</ion-item>
    <div [innerHTML]=newItem></div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

In my typescript class for the component I have a function addTodo(), which sets the HTML for "newItem" when the pluss/add icon in the right corner is pressed:

```
  addTodo(){
    this.newItem = "<ion-item>test</ion-item>";
  }
```

For some reason the "ion-item" tag is ignored on compilation and it only inserts "test" to the div element.

The appliction will look like this:

[image]

Component class:

[image]

So I tried to add this to the view:

```
<form *ngIf="editedItem">
  <ion-item><input [(ngModel)]="newItem" name="newItem">
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="btnCancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="btnAdd()">Add</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

But now when I click cancel or add, the page needs to reload.
I know I'm doing something wrong with the [(ngModel)]="newItem", should I try to pass the Angular variable over to the model or is there a better way to do this.

edit: Passed the variable over to the (click) function, as seen in @JoeriShoeby 's answer below.

In the model:

```
export class TodosPage {

newItem = "";
todos: string[] = this.getTodos();
editedItem: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  addTodo(){
    this.editedItem = true;
  }

  btnAdd(){
    this.todos.push(this.newItem);
    this.editedItem = false;
  }

  btnCancel(){
    this.editedItem = false;
  }

  getTodos(): string[]{

    return ["item 1", "item 2"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me your component class ? You actually need to push a new item object into the 'todos' array. Not html

Comment: I've added the component class to the post. I thought I might just update the array, but I want the new item to take input, and have buttons for saving and canceling. I thought maybe I could make a new component for the addTodo() content. But I can't figure out how to dynamically add a component with a function.

Comment: Give me an hour, then I have a computer to code it for you to explain

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated ^^

Comment: Couple things to note..  This  `[innerHTML]=newItem` should be `[innerHTML]="newItem"`. Secondly, if you use innerHTML you will not have access to any events, bindings, interpolation that you may have tried to add to that HTML. I would also suggest providing a demo to help get a better answer. http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/

Comment: You're not using angular how it's supposed to be used. In ANgular, the point of truth is the model, not the view. You modify the view by modifying the model. Based on the new model, the view refreshes itself and shows the new state of the model. To add a new item, add a new element to the `todos` array. The view will then refresh: ngFor will notice there is a new element, and will add a new item to the page.

Comment: The problem by just adding the element to the "todos" array is that it's not supposed to be just a new todo, but take input and have buttons for saving and canceling. So if you pressed save it would then add it to the array and show it, while the item which takes input is removed.

Comment: Then add a field `editedItem` to your component, set to null initially. When clicking the button, initialize it to a new, empty item. And in your view, add a `<form *ngIf="editedItem">...</form>` to edit the item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML file

```
// Your plus-icon in your header bar
<button (click)='toggleNew == true'>
    <ion-icon name='plus'></ion-icon>
</button>

// Your content
<ion-content>

  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of todos" (click)="edit(item)">
      {{item}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngIf='toggleNew'>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]='newItem' placeholder="Task .. "></ion-input>
        <button (click)='saveNew(newItem)'>Save</button>
        <button danger (click)='cancelNew()'>Cancel</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Your component

```
// Initalial values.
newItem: string = "";
toggleNew: boolean = false;

// Saving function
saveNew( newItem: string ): void {
    this.todos.push(newItem);
    this.toggleNew = false;
    this.newItem = "";
}

// Cancel function
cancelNew(): void {
    this.toggleNew = false;
    this.newItem = "";
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, and looked good too. Except now the buttons won't show up. Did you got them showing? I tried with the <ion-buttons end> tags and without.

Comment: Create a button within a <ion buttons-end> tag, and within that button the corresponding icon/text

Comment: <ion buttons-end> gives me an error and the page won't load. Maybe this is something of ionic 1 and not 2?

Console output:
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ion' is not a known element:

Comment: I can get them to show anywhere else but inside the ion-item when there's also an ion-input.

Comment: You'll need to use a <ion-buttons end>.

Comment: I did that, as I said in the first comment.

Comment: I am sorry, add a type="button" attribute to your buttons, this is because a button will act as a submit button by default when placed within a form.

Comment: That didn't work either. I can get them to show within normal input tags but that would look horrible on a mobile device, I will need to stick with ion-input. I have removed the form tags as they made the application reload whenever the input was given.

Comment: So I really don't understand you anymore ? What is not working yet ? What is what you actually want to achieve? My last comment should fix the reload issue

Comment: I think I've been clear about that. The buttons won't show up when inside the ion-item tags when there's also ion-input tags. It would be nice if the buttons was on the same line as the input field. There may be other ways to make them appear beside the ion-item, but I want to know if you can somehow make them appear when inside the same tags as the ion-input is inside (ion-item). The "reload issue" was never a problem, only when using a normal form, which I don't, so it's not an issue. Just to be clear "the buttons won't show up when inside the ion-item along with the ion-input tags".